# Asp.Net MVC Razor app with AngularJS migration to Angular 8

Tags: .net, angularjs, visual-studio, razor, angular-upgrade

I have a .Net web app running .Net Framework 4.6.1 with Razor and AngularJS 1.7.5 and we wish to migrate to Angular 8.

- Routing is being done in .Net.
- The HTML contains both Razor and AngularJS logic to render the UI.

Sample Razor/Angular HTML:

```
<div id="container" ng-controller="MyController">
     @Html.Action("MyView", "Home")
</div>
```

Sample AngularJS logic Code:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.doSomething= function () {
             //do stuff
        }            
    }
]);
```

1. We wish to do a hybrid migration. Is this possible?
2. Would it be easier to rewrite the app from scratch?
3. What are our options?

EDIT: This question is unique because it involves migrating a server-side rendered AngularJS .Net Application - Not client-side to Angular 8. I have heard of Angular Univeral which does just that but I want to know other options and if a hybrid approach is a possibility.

Comment: This question is unique because it involves migrating a server-side rendered AngularJS .Net Application - Not client-side to Angular 8. I have heard of Angular Univeral which does (but uses Node.js) just that but I want to know other options and if a hybrid approach is a possibility.

Answer (score -1):

Angular 2 or above is not an upgrade of Angular 1 because it is completely rewritten, it's a new framework.

So the second question I think would be the right choice. ("Would it be easier to rewrite the app from scratch?)

Regards

Comment: That is a matter of opinion. One of the keys to a successful upgrade is to do it incrementally, by running the two frameworks side by side in the same application, and porting AngularJS components to Angular one by one.

Comment: @georgeawg is a side by side upgrade a possibility in this scenario? I was unsure because Angular is client-side rendering and the current setup uses .Net Razor Pages to render server-side.